# Install crcmod CRC32C C extension on Alpine

Tags: python, gcloud, gsutil, alpine-linux

I'm trying to migrate my CI build to an alpine based docker image.

Part of the build is retrieving artifacts from Firebase testlab using the `gsutil` command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r -U $BUCKET_DIR* $OUTPUT_DIR
```

This command is failing because it can not perform the CRC check on the downloaded artifacts:

```
CommandException: 
Downloading this composite object requires integrity checking with CRC32c, but your crcmod installation isn't using the module's C extension, so the hash computation will likely throttle download performance. For help installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".

To download regardless of crcmod performance or to skip slow integrity checks, see the "check_hashes" option in your boto config file.

NOTE: It is strongly recommended that you not disable integrity checks. 
Doing so could allow data corruption to go undetected during uploading/downloading.
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

`gsutil help crcmod` doesn't provide instructions on how to install the C extension on Alpine.

I have tried installing the following packages, and while the installation of them is successful, the C extension is not installed and still causes the gsutil command to fail with the same error.

```
apk add --update --no-cache python py-pip gcc python-dev
pip install -U crcmod
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure there must be better options of doing this, but this is my workaround

```
# Install Alpine Python dependencies
apk add --update --no-cache python python-dev gcc musl-dev 

# Compile CRC32c
# See for more information: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod
#
curl -L -o crcmod.tar.gz "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/crcmod/crcmod/crcmod-1.7/crcmod-1.7.tar.gz"
tar -xzf crcmod.tar.gz
cd crcmod-1.7/
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem in py-crcmod package. There’s some .so file (`_crcfunext.so`), but maybe it does not work for some reason? Please open an issue on https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/projects/alpine/issues.